# Issue with legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

So I have a comparison bar chart, that plots the data correctly, but whenever I try to call the legend method I keep getting an error saying "No handles with labels found to put in legend"

```
def plotSiteByYear(dict1, dict2):
    ''' creates a bar chart comparison of the cancer sites of chosen years
    '''
    values1 = dict1.values()    # y values of dictionaries
    values2 = dict2.values()

    oKeys = []                  # creating empty lists first
    nKeys = []
    oKeys = list(dict1.keys())  # x values of dictionaries
    nKeys = list(dict2.keys())

    x1 = list(range(len(oKeys)))

    ind = np.arange(len(dict1))
    width = 0.4
    opacity = 0.7

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    #plotting older year (2005)
    rects1 = plt.bar(ind - width/2, values1, width, alpha = opacity, color = '#2d4dff', align='center',)
    #plotting more recent year (2015)
    rect2 = plt.bar(ind + width/2, values2, width, alpha = opacity, color = '#d4bee8', align='center')

    # labels / legend
    ax.set_ylabel('Number of Cancer Incidences')
    ax.set_xlabel('Location of Cancer Site')
    ax.set_title('Number of Cancer Incidences by Site in 2005 vs. 2015')
    ax.set_xticks(x1)
    ax.set_xticklabels(oKeys, rotation=90)
    # need to add a legend
    ax.legend()

    plt.show()
```

Everything else for my bar chart is right, but I can't get the legend to appear

Comment: The legend wouldn't know what to show. So you need to tell it via the bar's `label`. `plt.bar(..., label="my first legend entry")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`legend()` shows the "label" values. You can set them in the plot function, or with `set_label()`

Try:

```
rects1.set_label("MyLabel")
ax.legend()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because while plotting the bar chart, you did not specify any labels. The easiest way is to pass the labels while plotting. In your case, it would look like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

rects1 = plt.bar(ind - width/2, values1, width, alpha=opacity, 
                 color='#2d4dff', align='center',label='2005') # <--- Label added here

rect2 = plt.bar(ind + width/2, values2, width, alpha=opacity, 
                color='#d4bee8', align='center', label='2015') # <--- Label added here

# Rest of the code
ax.legend()
```